# Using socket to communicate with XML API openssl s_client -connect with Java

Tags: java, websocket, openvas

I am able to use xml API (of OpenVAS) using openssl like:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:9390 
...certificate info...
<get_version/>
<get_version_response status="200" status_text="OK"><version>7.0</version></get_version_response>
DONE
```

I am trying to achieve the same thing in `java` code with:

```
@Test
public void tryOpenVasGetVersion() throws InterruptedException,
        ExecutionException {

    WebSocketClient webSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();
    WebSocketSession webSocketSession = webSocketClient.doHandshake(new TextWebSocketHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) {
            System.out.println("received message - " + message.getPayload());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws InterruptedException {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            System.out.println("established connection - " + session);
        }
    }, new WebSocketHttpHeaders(), URI.create("wss://127.0.0.1:9390")).get();

    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        try {
            TextMessage message = new TextMessage("<get_version/>");
            webSocketSession.sendMessage(message);
            System.out.println("sent message - " + message.getPayload());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception while sending a message "+ e);
        }
    }, 1, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

but all I get is:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the
>   WebSocket connection failed
>
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
>   pl.corpnet.mixer.plugins.codescan.fortify.apiclient.SocketTest.connect(SocketTest.java:51)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)    at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>   Caused by: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to
>   initiate the WebSocket connection failed  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServerRecursive(WsWebSocketContainer.java:484)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient.lambda$doHandshakeInternal$0(StandardWebSocketClient.java:150)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected Status of SSLEngineResult
>   after an unwrap() operation   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperSecure$WrapperFuture.get(AsyncChannelWrapperSecure.java:512)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.processResponse(WsWebSocketContainer.java:783)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServerRecursive(WsWebSocketContainer.java:347)
>     ... 4 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected
>   Status of SSLEngineResult after an unwrap() operation     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperSecure$ReadTask.run(AsyncChannelWrapperSecure.java:314)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     ... 1 more

can anyone give me a hint if I can achieve the same thing using `WebSocketClient` as using openssl s_cllient -connect?

Comment: This is not a "real" answer but just a hint: The XML API (GMP) of OpenVAS/GVM doesn't use the WebSocket technology so you can't use websocket based code to communicate with the API.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to connect with creation of SSLSocket.

```java
SSLContext context = SSLContextBuilder.create().setProtocol("TLS1.2").setKeyStoreType("JKS").loadKeyMaterial(...).build();
SSLFactory factory = context.getSocketFactory();

SSLSocket socket = factory.createSocket(host, port);
```

it worked for me last year with openvas on kali linux.